# Pixel 7 Pro Always on display and tap to check phone stopped working after latest OS update (Android version 14)

Tags: settings, gestures

I've recently installed the latest upgrade for the Android OS, and since then, the "always on display" and "tap to check phone" features have stopped working. I've tried disabling and reenabling. I've confirmed that I am not on battery saver mode.

Is there anything else I can do? Is there a way to contact Google support? I've tried looking online to no avail.

Things I've already tried and that have not worked:

- Force booting phone
- Turning off bluetooth
- Turning off screensaver
- Clear cache and storage for Android Auto
- Turning on/off notification for Car Mode in the Android System app.